# How to create a variable name that includes a DateTime value

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, variables

I'm writing a function that declares 3 variables for each day (morning,midday,evening). I want these to be essentially named something like: 'morning_241222' etc.

I don't know how to automate variable declaration to have unique naming in Python 3 as well as how to create variable names that incorporating values from other places.

it obviously didn't work, but I tried:

`today_%d%m%y = "test"`

Comment: Creating variables with variable names is not the way to go. Use a dictionary with key/value pairs

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can tray vars() to assign string to variable name.
this code works:

```
myVar = vars()
myVar['today_{}'.format("241222")] = 20
print(today_241222)
```

output will be:

```
20
```